# Nservicebus 5 and later Web Api Depenedency Injection settings

Tags: nservicebus

How can I configure Web api dependency settings for NserviceBus 5 and later version.

Version 3 or 4 is like this:

```
public static class ConfigureWebApi
{
    public static Configure ForWebApi(this Configure configure)
    {
        // Register our http controller activator with NSB
        configure.Configurer.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
            new NSBHttpControllerActivator());

        // Find every http controller class so that we can register it
        var controllers = Configure.TypesToScan
            .Where(t => typeof(IHttpController).IsAssignableFrom(t));

        // Register each http controller class with the NServiceBus container
        foreach (Type type in controllers)
            configure.Configurer.ConfigureComponent(type, ComponentCallModelEnum.Singlecall);

        // Set the WebApi dependency resolver to use our resolver
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(new NServiceBusResolverAdapter(configure.Builder));

        // Required by the fluent configuration semantics
        return configure;
    }
}
```

But Version 5 does not use `Configure` class, that use `BusConfiguration`

I try this but can not scan assemblies:

```
public static class ConfigureWebApi
{
    public static BusConfiguration ForWebApi(this BusConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.RegisterComponents(c => c.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), 
            new NServiceBusHttpControllerActivator()));

        ????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which way you're thinking. I'm asking, because I might be wrong with my answer. If so, let me know and I'll try to update it.

The way I go about this issue is setting up the container first and then have NServiceBus use that container. I'm using AutoFac and create a special class to set it up.

Disclaimer : I'm copying this from an existing app and didn't try nor compile it. I'm 100% sure this is working though, although I might've forgotten a line or added one too much! :)

```
public class DependenciesConfig
{
    public static IContainer RegisterDependencies()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // MVC Controllers
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())

        // WebAPI controllers
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

        // Way more registrations

        // Next line is AutoFac specific for WebAPI
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
        var container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        return container;

    }
}
```

Then I have an additional class for registering NServiceBus. I don't have handlers in my web app, nor do I publish messages, so I use a SendOnly endpoint.

```
public class ServiceBus
{
    public static ISendOnlyBus Bus { get; private set; }
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static void Init(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        if (Bus != null) return;

        NServiceBus.Logging.LogManager.Use<CommonLoggingFactory>();

        lock (padlock)
        {
            if (Bus != null) return;

            var configuration = new BusConfiguration();
            configuration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
            configuration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(x => x.ExistingLifetimeScope(container));
            configuration.UseTransport<AzureStorageQueueTransport>();

            ConventionsBuilder conventions = configuration.Conventions();
            conventions.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Messages") && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"));

            Bus = NServiceBus.Bus.CreateSendOnly(configuration);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: You can move the NSB Config code to the app start, and once you 'reuse' the same container instance in both places (your registrations and then NServiceBus config), you can just inject IBus in your controllers like any other dependency.

Why take an static dependency to IBus while you already have an IoC container, right?